# How to set defaultValue of a radioGroup from a nested Array object in React state?

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, nested, state

I have this array Object in State called formRating

```
formRating:Array[22]
0:
 {…}
  condId: "C2.1(a)"
  rate: "N/A"
1:
 {…}
  condId:"C2.2(b)"
  rate:"3"
2:
 {…}
3:
 {…}
```

I also have a few RadioGroups in the render letting the user manipulate the state object above.

```
<Grid item xs={7} style={{marginTop:32}}> Condition 1</Grid> <Grid item ><RadioGroup name="C2.1(a)"  defaultValue={this.getDefaultValue('C2.1(a)')} onChange={this.changeButton("C2.1(a)")} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
```

What would the getDefaultValue method be to change the rate of an element matching with the given condId with the defaultValue={this.getDefaultValue("C2.1(a)")}?

Comment: It all depends on what you would like to change the values to. What would the user be doing to update this value?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I have the onChange method already. Looking for a method to set the defaultValue of the radioGroup by fetching the respective rate of the given condId. Any help is deeply appreciated :D

Comment: Oh, it would be easier to understand what you're trying to do if we can see the code inside your render method.

Comment: <Grid item xs={7} style={{marginTop:32}}> Condition 1 </Grid> <Grid item ><RadioGroup name="C2.1(a)"  defaultValue={this.getDefaultValue('C2.1(a)')} onChange={this.changeButton("C2.1(a)")} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>

Comment: i updated the question above Christopher

Comment: gotcha, im working on a solution, what library is this coming from to get the Grid and RadioGroup?

Comment: it's materialUI :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Your solution worked. However i did tweak it a little bit to be access the state passed through props :D

Wanted to accept it as the answer cant seem to find it?

Comment: Awesome I'm glad that worked for you and I see your updated code works well. :)   I don't know what happened to my answer, but I was able to bring it back. Please accept it when you get the chance. :D

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Would you also be able to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351463/how-to-modify-an-existing-pdf-in-react-js as well? :)

Comment: I can take a look at it! But admittedly I know nothing about PDFs :(

Comment: Any and all help is appreciated. Like i said I'm a total newbie. Come from a Java and SQL background not JavaScript and React. But I figured I gotta start learning somewhere aha

Comment: Welcome to the front-end my friend. :)

Comment: Thanks mate. Please have look at the other question and help me out if possible aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make sense to define the `defaultValue` of these `RadioGroups` by using a `.map()` to iterate over the list of `formRatings`. Then you can pass in the rate seamlessly instead of passing a hard-coded string to a function.

Try something like:

```
  createRadioGroups = () => {
    const { formRating } = this.state;

    return formRating.map(item => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{item.condId}</label>
          <Grid item>
            <RadioGroup
              defaultValue={item.rate}
              value={item.rate}
              name={item.condId}
              onChange={() => this.changeButton(item.condId)}
            />
          </Grid>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

Then in your render you can use `createRadioGroups()`

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid item xs={7} style={{ marginTop: 32 }}>
          Condition 1
        </Grid>
        {this.createRadioGroups()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I get the following error>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
LessonOne.createRadioGroups
src/components/addrecord/LessonOne.js:128
  125 | 
  126 | const {formRating}=this.state;
  127 | 
> 128 | return formRating.map(item => {
      | ^  129 |   return (
  130 |     <Grid container>
  131 |       <Grid item xs={8}>conditon goes here </Grid>

Comment: update -  i am using fetch to setState formRating where data is retrieved from the API as a JSON object. And i am presented with a .map is not a function error or cannot find property .map of undefined. any steps involved before using JSon data in state? like a conversion process or anything?

Answer (score 1):

With @ChristopherNgo inspiration, following worked.

In the render;

```
<Grid item xs={12} style={{marginTop:20}}>{this.createRadioGroups(values.formRating)}</Grid>
```

and createRadioGroups method as follows;

```
 createRadioGroups = (ratingState)=>{
   return(ratingState.map(
    item =>
     <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{marginTop:20, marginRight:0}}>{item.condId} </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={6} style={{marginTop:20}}>{item.condition} </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} style={{marginTop:10}}>
            <RadioGroup defaultValue={item.rate} name={item.condId}  onChange={this.changeButton(item.condId)} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <FormControlLabel value="1" control={<Radio color="primary" />} label='' labelPlacement="top"/>
              <FormControlLabel value="2" control={<Radio color="primary" />}label='' labelPlacement="top"/>
              <FormControlLabel value="3" control={<Radio color="primary" />}label='' labelPlacement="top"/>
              <FormControlLabel value="N/A" control={<Radio color="primary" />}label='' labelPlacement="top"/>
            </RadioGroup>
          </Grid>

      </Grid>

))
```

}
  ;